# Report Server option on SQL Server Management Studio Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to connect to a SQL Server Reporting Services Report Server from SQL Server Management Studio Express. Unfortunately there is no "Report Server" option in the "Server Type" drop down. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The base Express Edition doesn't include Reporting Services.  You'll have to install the Express Edition with Advanced Services.

Comment: I installed with advanced service. I can have report server running on same box accessible from localhost/report url. I am not just able to connect it via management studio.

Comment: I believe this is true...you can't connect to Reporting Services through Management Studio Express.  I think that's what this MSDN article says too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx.  What are you trying to do?  There may be another way to do it without Management Studio (eg. Reporting Services Configuration tool).

Answer (score 0):

This error happens some time, try install the serice pack, if this don't work try to re-install, I been see this error before, and that works for me.

See Ya.